# Type-checking a TypeScript reducer receiving action types

Tags: typescript, redux

I am trying to create a TypeScript redux reducer that accepts an actionType as a key value, however I am struggling to define the proper interface for my state. When doing so, I am getting the following message:

> TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'SampleState'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'SampleState'.

[image]

How do I properly type check my reducer for when it receives an actionType? Thanks, you can see the sample code below.

**sampleActionTypes.ts:**

```
export const FOO = 'FOO';
export const BAR = 'BAR';
export const TURN_ON = 'TURN_ON';
export const TURN_OFF = 'TURN_OFF';

interface TurnOn {
  type: typeof TURN_ON;
  actionType: string;
}

interface TurnOff {
  type: typeof TURN_OFF;
  actionType: string;
}

export type Types = TurnOn | TurnOff;
```

**sampleReducer.ts:**

```
import { BAR, FOO, TURN_OFF, TURN_ON, Types } from './sampleActionTypes';

export interface SampleState {
  [FOO]: {
    toggle: boolean;
  };
  [BAR]: {
    toggle: boolean;
  };
}

const initialState: SampleState = {
  [FOO]: {
    toggle: false,
  },
  [BAR]: {
    toggle: false,
  },
};

const sampleReducer = (state = initialState, action: Types): SampleState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TURN_ON:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.actionType]: {
          ...state[action.actionType],
          toggle: true,
        },
      };
    case TURN_OFF:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.actionType]: {
          ...state[action.actionType],
          toggle: false,
        },
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default sampleReducer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the `SampleState` interface to the following solved this issue:

```
export interface SampleState {
  [key: string]: {
    toggle: boolean;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your state has as keys `FOO | BAR` following your `SampleState` interface.
And your `Types['actionType']` is `string`.

So when you're doing `state[action.actionType]`, you're doing `SampleState[string]`. But `SampleState` accepts only `FOO` or `BAR` !

A solution, according to your needs, may be to type `Types['actionType']: (typeof FOO) | (typeof BAR)` (something like that).

Also carefull to how you're naming your fields. Maybe it's just for the example, but `actionType` when there is already a `type` in an action interface seems redondant and quite confusing.